# Geoserver WFS-T with mapping file not inserting features

Tags: geoserver, wfs-t, mongodb, geoserver-app-schema

I am wondering if this is supported and could not find the answer yet.

I did my setup according to https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/app-schema/mongo-tutorial.html

and by the above mentioned tutorial, I was able to get following **response** via calling WFS GetFeature

[image]

My problem is **inserting** which I do this way:

```
<!--
      YOU PROBABLY DO NOT WANT TO RUN THIS QUERY SINCE 
       IT WILL MODIFY YOUR SOURCE DATA FILES
       
       It will add a simple line to the tasmania_roads dataset.
       
  -->
<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="2.0.0"
   xmlns:mapped-features-workspace="http://www.stations.org/1.0" 
   xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
   xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2
  http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd">
  <wfs:Insert>
   <mapped-features-workspace:StationFeature gml:id="10">
            <mapped-features-workspace:name>station 24</mapped-features-workspace:name>
            <mapped-features-workspace:contact>
                <mapped-features-workspace:mail>station1@mail.com</mapped-features-workspace:mail>
            </mapped-features-workspace:contact>
            <mapped-features-workspace:measurement>
                <mapped-features-workspace:Measurement>
                    <mapped-features-workspace:name>temp</mapped-features-workspace:name>
                    <mapped-features-workspace:unit>c</mapped-features-workspace:unit>
                    <mapped-features-workspace:values>
                        <mapped-features-workspace:Value>
                            <mapped-features-workspace:timestamp>1482146800</mapped-features-workspace:timestamp>
                            <mapped-features-workspace:value>20.0</mapped-features-workspace:value>
                        </mapped-features-workspace:Value>
                    </mapped-features-workspace:values>
                </mapped-features-workspace:Measurement>
            </mapped-features-workspace:measurement>
            <mapped-features-workspace:measurement>
                <mapped-features-workspace:Measurement>
                    <mapped-features-workspace:name>wind</mapped-features-workspace:name>
                    <mapped-features-workspace:unit>km/h</mapped-features-workspace:unit>
                    <mapped-features-workspace:values>
                        <mapped-features-workspace:Value>
                            <mapped-features-workspace:timestamp>1482146833</mapped-features-workspace:timestamp>
                            <mapped-features-workspace:value>155.0</mapped-features-workspace:value>
                        </mapped-features-workspace:Value>
                    </mapped-features-workspace:values>
                </mapped-features-workspace:Measurement>
            </mapped-features-workspace:measurement>
            <mapped-features-workspace:geometry/>
        </mapped-features-workspace:StationFeature>
  </wfs:Insert>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

I am getting **Could not parse input features**

When I debugged GeoServer it has weird condition about SimpleFeatures, that says, if input is not simple feature, then throw error message. I am wondering, if that is a matter of support or maybe it is not being converted to simple features properly...

[image]

**GeoServer log output:**

```
2021-09-20 17:33:44,108 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Raw XML request starts with: <!--
      YOU PROBABLY DO NOT WANT TO RUN THIS QUERY SINCE 
       IT WILL MODIFY YOUR SOURCE DATA FILES
       
       It will add a simple line to the tasmania_roads dataset.
       
  -->
<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="2.0.0"
   xmlns:mapped-features-workspace="http://www.stations.org/1.0" 
   xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
   xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2
  http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd">
  <wfs:Insert>
   <mapped-features-workspace:StationFeature gml:id="12">
            <mapped-features-workspace:name>station 24</mapped-features-workspace:name>
            <mapped-features-workspace:contact>
                <mapped-features-workspace:mail>23@mail.com</mapped-features-workspace:mail>
            </mapped-features-workspace:contact>
            <mapped-features-workspace:measurement>
                <mapped-features-workspace:Measurement>
       ...
2021-09-20 17:33:44,110 INFO [org.geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2021-09-20 17:33:44,113 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wfs.xml] - Assuming hostname www.opengis.net does not refer to self.  If this is wrong may lead to deadlock.
2021-09-20 17:33:44,532 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of C:\Users\dusan.tichy\Downloads\geoserver-2.19.2-bin\data_dir\gwc-layers
2021-09-20 17:33:44,533 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - delta computed in 1ms for C:\Users\dusan.tichy\Downloads\geoserver-2.19.2-bin\data_dir\gwc-layers
2021-09-20 17:33:44,766 WARN [org.geotools.xsd.impl] - Schema location not specified as namespace/location pair. Ignoring http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd
2021-09-20 17:33:44,776 ERROR [org.geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.wfs.WFSException: Could not parse input features
    at org.geoserver.wfs.InsertElementHandler.getTypeNames(InsertElementHandler.java:289)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction.execute(Transaction.java:169)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction.transaction(Transaction.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.DefaultWebFeatureService20.transaction(DefaultWebFeatureService20.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor346.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:50)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy108.transaction(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor345.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:876)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:265)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsync.service(ServletHolder.java:1452)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-09-20 17:33:44,779 DEBUG [org.geoserver.filters] - Compressing output for mimetype: application/xml
```

**I have found on GeoServer's JIRA (from 2016 that it is not supported, is it not implemented yet?) :**
https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-7483

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Answer (score 0):

GeoServer has no support for writing complex features, the mapping data stores are all read only. For a few selected mapping, that happen to have invertible "interpolations" (the expressions used in the mapping), it's theoretically possible to implement write support. For others, it's just plain impossible.

If you are interested, join either the developer list (if you're going to implement such support) or contact [some service provider to get a quotation](http://geoserver.org/comm/).